# PHP отдача файлов по расписанию

Tags: php, файлы, время

Суть такова: в директории есть несколько файлов. В зависимости от времени должен отдаваться определённый файл с определённого байта. К примеру, в 6:00 клиент получает в ответ на запрос файл № 1 с первого байта, в 6:01 - с 20, в 7:00 - файл №2 и т. д.
Заранее благодарен за ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [fseek](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fseek.php) — Устанавливает смещение в файловом указателе.

```php
<?php

function getDataByTime($time) {
    list($hour, $minute) = explode(':', $time);

    $minutes = $hour * 60 + $minute;

    if ($minutes <= 360) {
        // До 6:00
        $file = 'file1';
        $offset = 0;
    } elseif ($minutes > 360 && $minutes <= 420) {
        // С 6:01 до 7:00
        $file = 'file2';
        $offset = 4;
    } elseif ($minutes > 420) {
        // С 7:01 и позже
        $file = 'file2';
        $offset = 8;
    }

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        $handle = fopen($file, 'r');

        fseek($handle, $offset);

        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file) - $offset);
        fpassthru($handle);
        exit;
    }
}

getDataByTime('7:01');
```